# Que exactamente sucedete en este flujo de codigo?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Necesito ayuda a entender esto completamente, entiendo que se recibe un objeto como parametro luego se asigna en item.name el mismo valor pero en mayuscula.

luego el condicional que verifica si es que existe un valor dentro de esta propiedad del objeto???

a partir de alli ya no entiendo mucho ,alguien que me explique por favor.

```html
function uppercaseAllTheThings( item ) {

item.name = item.name.toUpperCase();

if ( item.children ) {

item.children = item.children.map(

uppercaseAllTheThings )

}

return item;

}
```

gracias.

Comment: ¿Te has mirado lo que es [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children)?  Aparte de eso, es una función recursiva, pues si consigue meterse en los nodos hijos del elemento **item**, se los repasa todos con el **map** para ponerlos a todos en mayúsculas ejecutando la misma función de nuevo, y si tiene más hijos lo mismo, es decir, se recorre toda la jerarquía de nodos que tenga contenidos.

Comment: bueno, solo me dieron ese bloque de codigo como ejercicio. no hay mayor información. Gracias por la explicación.

Comment: Si estás aprendiendo y/o eres nuevo en el tema, olvídate del `no hay mayor información`, tienes acceso a internet y si algo no encuentras en español, busca en otro idioma, existen traductores online ("pero no traducen igual", te dan la idea base), por otro lado, revisa esto: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map Esta página de Mozilla será tu nueva biblia para aprender JavaScript, la documentación oficial es muy importante, marca una diferencia de los que hacen cosas y de los que esperan a que otros las hagan. Saludos.

Comment: Aquí tienes otro lugar para aprender JavaScript a punta de ejercicios: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/herramientas/javascript/basico/ y el legendario FreeCodeCamp: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/#basic-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el objeto 'item' el cual al menos tiene 2 propiedades

- name = Es un string
- children = Es una lista de otros elementos del tipo 'item'

Esto provoca una estructura de árbol, algo así:

- item (padre)

  - item (Hijo)

    - item (Nieto)
    - item (Nieto)
    - item (Nieto)
  - item (Hijo)

    - item (Nieto)
  - item (Hijo)

El árbol puedes ser más o menos profundo, donde cada nodo puede contar con más o menos hijos

Lo que busca tu función es colocar en mayúsculas todos los nombres de todos los nodos (padre, hijos, nietos, hermanos, etc) y lo hace con una función recursiva

Una función recursiva, es una función que dentro de ella se llama a sí misma nuevamente.

Uno de los elementos principales de las funciones recursivas es saber cuándo detener la recursividad, de lo contrario queda en un bucle infinito.

Esto lo hace con el if ( item.children ), de tal manera que si un nodo no tiene más hijos se detiene esta recursividad (para ese nodo)

Luego se emplea la función 'map' (función que tienen los array). Esta función opera parecido a un for. Lo que hace crear otro array a partir del primero cambiando cosas. Que cosas? pues lo que tu quieras, para esto debes colocar una función como parámetro. En tu caso colocaste la misma función ('uppercaseAllTheThings'). Es decir, este map, entrega un array de 'items' que han cambiado su 'name' a mayúsculas. Con lo cual, cambiaste a mayúsculas toda la estructura del árbol